# What does [1 note] means in Git(Lab)'s commit tree?

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

My company is using a private GitLab. I recently looked to the graph of branches and commits, and it showed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdHbG.png). A [1 note] label that looks like the labels GitLab uses to show the branches' heads (but "1 note" isn't one of our branches).

[image: (Screenshot of GitLab commit graph)]

When I browse through a CLI `git log`, I can't see anything related to that.

Does anyone know what this `[1 note]` means/represent ?

If context can help, here's what the dev did:

Looking at the [commit tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdHbG.png):

- Was on the bottom red commit
- Made the 2 green commits
- Made a `reset --hard` to the bottom red commit
- Made the middle red commit ([bugfix]...)
- Pulled the top green commit into its current commit (still middle red one), leading to a merge : the top red commit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I just found the origin of this label.

The commit has this label, because another commit has a comment looking like "blablabla ... id_of_the_famous_labeled_commit ... blablabla"

It seems that GitLab recognises that this is a commit's id, and link them.

Answer (score 0):

[git notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) is a way to attach information to Git objects (primarily commits) after they've been created. Since objects are immutable, the notes are stored in a separate ref (kind of a special branch).

To enable fetching notes from a remote, use:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*"
git fetch origin

git ls-remote origin | grep refs/notes
git ls-remote . | grep refs/notes
```

To display commit-related notes in `git log`, use:

```
git config notes.displayRef refs/notes/commits
```

Comment: As if Git wasn’t hard enough to teach...this is the first I’ve heard of notes.

Comment: Good news, most users don't need to be taught about it. (Frankly it's not a very useful feature either – the attached information is as easy to lose as actual post-it notes.)

Comment: I finally find where this thing comes from. And it's not git-notes, it's because its commit number (hash) is written in another commit's comment. I suppose this to be a GitLab functionnality, not a Git one.
But you just make me discover git-notes, thanks a lot for that !